# Connect between two branches

Tags: cisco, routing, router, network-core, network-access

Hope anyone help me to inform me how can connect  between two branches & what the technology use it and what devices need to pay on this project? ?

Sincerely,

Comment: Could you expand a bit more? - What type of applications will be used? - How many users? - What is your budget?

Comment: there are two location need to connect between together to access remotely to Pc's .used a domain, RDT and use local application installed in server at  the main branches ..

Comment: User around 20 users ,budget make do  this projector by a cheaper price as per IT manager..

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't provided anywhere near enough information to help you.  Where are these sites located?  What is your budget?  Cheaper than what?  What kind of network equipment is at each site?  Do the sites have Internet access?

Comment: Dear Mr:Ron  the location destinies far away like city to city...budget by cheaper cost ..equipment like cisco or sophos. .ect yes the sites must be access to Internet .

Comment: This question is really too broad, and it leads to opinion-based answers, both of which are off-topic here, as are product or resource recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many way you can achive it but most common are:

> 1. Site to site Ipsec tunnel over internet
> 2. MPLS circut
> 3. MetroEthernet

Comment: Dear datagram.network , thank you very much for your answer... hope you inform me which devices should be use on this project??

Comment: It depends of technology you use. Most common is Site to site IPsec tunnel over internet which require two devices (Routers, Firewalls) on both sites which could setup this connection. Border routers which are already in use could be used if they have this capabalities.

Comment: For example for SOHO you can use Cisco ASA 5505 or 5506 on both ends.

Comment: What about Sonicwall firewall it's work fine ??